# Triple Integral in spherical coordinate

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, spheres

$\displaystyle\iiint_R (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $R$ is in the region in the first octant outside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$;

Hi guys, I don't quite get which region is this, is it that I find the volume of this sphere and minus by the volume of the first octant? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use spherical coordinates, do you know the transformations for your variables?

Comment: hi boots, yea i know, is just that i dont quite understand the question. I am unsure what region is it that i required to calculate

Comment: I tried using the limit for the first octant of the sphere and it gives me the same answer as the answer sheet but from the question, it doesn't seem like it is asking for the first octant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This has nothing to do with computing volumes. The idea is to compute the integral of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-2}$ in the region of the first octant *outside* the unit sphre. Turning this into spherical coordinates, this becomes$$\int_1^\infty\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\rho^2\sin\varphi}{\rho^4}\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\varphi\,\mathrm d\rho.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps. I understand and got the answer as well.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.